# How to modify an invoice in quickbooks using qbxml and qbsdk13 in c#?

Tags: c#, sdk, quickbooks, qbxml

I have done an InvoiceModquery like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
  <?qbxml version="6.0"?> 
 <QBXML>
 <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
 <InvoiceModRq requestID="1">
 <InvoiceMod>
  <TxnID>79-1442638826</TxnID> 
  <EditSequence>1442638826</EditSequence> 
 <CustomerRef>
  <ListID>80000004-1442638803</ListID> 
  <FullName>Chris Evans</FullName> 
  </CustomerRef>
  <TxnDate>2015-09-19</TxnDate> 
  <RefNumber>5461</RefNumber> 
 <InvoiceLineMod>
 <ItemRef>
  <ListID>8000000A-1442469770</ListID> 
  <FullName>Item 1</FullName> 
  </ItemRef>
  <Quantity>1</Quantity> 
  <Rate>100.00</Rate> 
  </InvoiceLineMod>
  <InvoiceLineMod /> 
 <InvoiceLineMod>
 <ItemRef>
  <ListID>8000000B-1442469788</ListID> 
  <FullName>Item 2</FullName> 
  </ItemRef>
  <Quantity>1</Quantity> 
  <Rate>200.00</Rate> 
  </InvoiceLineMod>
  </InvoiceMod>
  </InvoiceModRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
  </QBXML>
```

when I send this request to the sdk I get an error saying quickbooks couldnot parse the provided xml. Please suggest where I am going wrong.

Comment: Got an answer to this question by reposting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32817070/how-to-modify-an-invoice-in-quickbooks-using-qbxml-and-qbsdk13)

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you need to provide valid XML for QuickBooks to process it. Your request above is not valid XML.

It's not valid XML because of the hyphens you have in your request (I'm guessing you copy/pasted this from somewhere that put the dashes in):

```
-<QBXML>
    -<QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        -<InvoiceModRq requestID="1">
```

Remove the hyphens, and try again.

You should also consider just copy/pasting your XML into any XML Validator tool found online, as that would have immediately showed you the errors.

Comment: These are present in every request I send to the qbsdk and all of them return valid results.

Comment: They aren't valid XML. If you want your request to work, you need to remove the hyphens.

Comment: The code I have pasted above is just a "XML visualizer view" of the request that I send. That kind of hyphen only appears in the XML visualizer.

Comment: Then post the ACTUAL XML that you are sending to QuickBooks. How are we supposed to help you if you show us something completely different from what you're actually sending to QuickBooks?

Comment: The above xml (without the hyphens) is my request.

Comment: If you can't take the time to post the actual raw XML you're sending, and the actual error message from QuickBooks, I can't take the time to help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90319/discussion-between-mainak-and-keith-palmer-consolibyte).

Comment: QuickBooks *can not* generate this error message unless you're sending malformed XML. If you want help, we *MUST* see the raw XML that you're sending to QuickBooks. Not something that you're copy/pasting from some XML editor, but the raw XML that you actually send to QuickBooks. End of story. You want help, you post the XML you're sending to QuickBooks.