# How to modify an invoice in quickbooks using qbxml and qbsdk13?

Tags: c#, quickbooks, qbxml

This is my QBXML request

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<?qbxml version="6.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <InvoiceModRq requestID="1">
            <InvoiceMod>
                <TxnID>85-1442639879</TxnID>
                <EditSequence>1442639879</EditSequence>
                <CustomerRef>
                    <ListID>80000005-1442639850</ListID>
                    <FullName>Bruce Banner</FullName>
                </CustomerRef>
                <TxnDate>2015-09-19</TxnDate>
                <RefNumber>5462</RefNumber>
                <InvoiceLineMod>
                    <ItemRef>
                        <ListID>8000000A-1442469770</ListID>
                        <FullName>Item 1</FullName>
                    </ItemRef>
                    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                    <Rate>1100.00</Rate>
                </InvoiceLineMod>
            </InvoiceMod>
        </InvoiceModRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

I am getting an error 
QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream.

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to the QuickBooks OSR:

- https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html

You'll notice that within the `<InvoiceLineMod>` element, this node is *required*:

- `<TxnLineID>`

The OSR gives you a bit more information too:

> **TxnLineID**
>
> Identification number of the transaction line. (TxnLineID
>   is supported as of v2.0 of the SDK. With qbXML v1.0 and v1.1,
>   TxnLineID is always returned as zero.)
>
> If you need to add a new transaction line in a transaction Mod
>   request, you can do so by setting the TxnLineID to -1.

So, you'll need to add in a `<TxnLineID>` node. If it's a new line item, put `-1` for the content within the node. If it's an existing line you're trying to update, put the `TxnLineID` value of the existing line in there.

Example:

```
...
<InvoiceLineMod>
    <TxnLineID>-1</TxnLineID>
    <ItemRef>
        <ListID>8000000A-1442469770</ListID>
        <FullName>Item 1</FullName>
    </ItemRef>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <Rate>1100.00</Rate>
</InvoiceLineMod>
...
```